Binary variable taking floating values in multi trip VRP with TW
I am trying to solve a multi trip VRP with time windows in pulp (minimizing total distance travelled). The code is providing optimal results for multi trip VRP without time window constraints (however subtour variable (u) values are not correct).
However, when I add time window constraints to the model, the binary variables defined in code are taking float values.
The binary variable x(i,j,v,r) where i and j are nodes, v are vehicles and r is trip index, takes multiple float values for same nodes and different trips like
x(0,1,1,1) = 0.99, x(0,1,1,2) = 0.01. The continuous time variable also takes different float values for different trips. I am not sure why is it happening and what could be the solution?

Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/5163/500
